# Multiple camera previews from same camera x not working as intended

Tags: android, android-studio, android-jetpack, android-camerax

I've been trying to make a camera preview using CameraX on android studio, and I managed to get two instances of the preview loaded. However, when I run it, the camera previews show different parts of the same camera view; I want sort of a cropped version of the camera view, but in both previews. I'll put a picture to describe it, and just the xml code.

```
    <androidx.camera.view.PreviewView
        android:id="@+id/viewFinderLeft"
        android:layout_width="329dp"
        android:layout_height="428dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.camera.view.PreviewView
        android:id="@+id/viewFinderRight"
        android:layout_width="331dp"
        android:layout_height="421dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

[imgur link to the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a5KIz.png)

Comment: you might need to crop for each previewView yourself?

Comment: yeah about that, can you explain how to crop previewviews? I can't find it in the attributes panel so I don't know how

Comment: set the first one to app:scaleType="fillStart"; the second one to app:scaleType="fillEnd" for a test; but the solution is to change the transform in each view.

Comment: Ok, I've tried the fill start and fill end code; however, I'm still not sure what you mean by transforming in each view. I've tried using the translation x attribute, but this is all I managed to get. You've mentioned cropping, which I still can't figure out how to do, but my main concern is that the camera perspective shot itself stays in the same position in both previews.
[image explaining what i mean](https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/643964775457619970/912584598498713630/unknown.png?width=536&height=676)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70162945/4496512 is the right answer to this question.

Answer (score 3):

CameraX does not officially support two `Preview`s. It might work, but there is no guarantee it will work across all the supported devices. Sounds like you want to display the preview stream in two different places. There are some ideas that you can try out:

- Use one `PreviewView`. Use a overlay view top of it to hide the part you don't want.
- "Fan out" the camera stream. Instead of using `PreviewView`, you can use a `SurfaceTexture` to get the preview output as a GLES texture then use it to draw into different `Surface`s. This will require quite a bit of work. A simpler but less efficient way is to get camera frames via `ImageAnalysis` and perform the buffer copy on CPU.

Comment: Is there an example of using point 2?